# jquery producing margin issues in Safari only

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, safari, responsive-design

Using a responsive caroufredsel, works like a charm in Chrome & Firefox, but in Safari it is suddenly producing top and bottom margins of 800px, throwing everything off.

Its a responsive site, and strangely the issue doesn't occur when influenced by the media query for screens of 500px wide or less.

The site is a wordpress custom build, waiting on a server for the domain to be mapped across when all is ready to go.

live page:

```
http://109.203.120.0/~wirebird/wordpress/the-guitars/
```

The [static html version](http://www.wirebirdguitars.com/staging/guitars.html) works fine, so is it a wordpress issue, or the fact that it is not using a true domain yet?

jquery for firing caroufredsel below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("#guitars-gallery").carouFredSel({
auto: false,
circular: false,
prev: '#prev',
next: '#next',
responsive : true,
height : 500,
scroll: 1,
items : { width : 370, height : 500, visible : { min : 1, max : 3 } } });   

});

function doSomething() {

jQuery('#guitars-gallery').trigger('destroy', true);
jQuery('#guitars-gallery').css({'text-align': '','float': '','position': '','top': '','right': '','bottom': '','left': '','width': '90%','height': '','margin': '1% auto'});

jQuery("#guitars-gallery").carouFredSel({
auto: false,
circular: false,
prev: '#prev',
next: '#next',
responsive : true,
height : 500,
scroll: 1,
items : { width : 370, height : 500, visible : { min : 1, max : 3 } } });

};

var resizeTimer;

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
resizeTimer = setTimeout(doSomething, 100);
});
```

Any ideas most welcome, it's driving me mad!

UPDATE: I have resolved this for now by using jquery to change the styling after the carousel is called:

```
jQuery('.caroufredsel_wrapper').css({'margin-top': '0px', 'margin-bottom': '0px'});
```

Fixes the problem, but I'm still none the wiser as to why it was happening :-)

Comment: I thought the selector for jQuery was `$`, not `jQuery`...

Comment: One of your script is not able to loaded & there are many places tou used "rem" as unit.

Comment: @Bluefire You can use both **$** or **jQuery** as a selector, as of avoiding conflicts with other frameworks. This says the manual: **By default, jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery"**, look here: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys - 

@SVS Good spot on the apparent script which wasn't loading - turns out that error was not an unloaded script, but triggered by an html typo which has been fixed. The main problem is still outstanding however.

Also, rem is a valid unit which helps avoid writing rules that select nested elements to reset them back to 1em (http://css-tricks.com/font-sizing-with-rem/)

Comment: couldn't connect to host

Answer (score 0):

I would check your theme's stylesheet in wordpress to make sure you don't have any conflicting styles.

Were you always calling  `.caroufredsel_wrapper` as opposed to `.wrapper` ?